# What are the statistics on how many people download the Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, stats

What are the statistics on how many people download the Tor Browser? How many people download it? How many update it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org) has a visualization of Tor Browser downloads and updates,

[image]

It also has statistics on Tor Browser downloads by platform,

[image]

In addition to statistics on Tor Browser downloads by locale,

[image]

---

[Blog post](https://metrics.torproject.org/webstats-tb-locale.html) on Tor Browser section of Tor Metrics.